# stanford dependency parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have tried stanford dependency parser. I got the following parse tree and relation.But I need a dependency graph. How to get it. Is there any way to covert the dependencies to graph? Please help me. I am new to java and stanford tools.

Program is a set of instruction

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Program))
    (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP
        (NP (DT a) (NN set))
        (PP (IN of)
          (NP (NN instruction)))))))

nsubj(set-4, Program-1)
cop(set-4, is-2)
det(set-4, a-3)
root(ROOT-0, set-4)
prep_of(set-4, instruction-6)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: There are a few implemenations of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph out there. These are good for dependencies as it stops you having cycles in your dependency tree.

Comment: As ar as I understand, each line in the lower portion of the example represents an edge in the graph, i.e. there is a node `set` and a node `Program` and an edge labeled `nsubj` connecting the two, etc.

Comment: yes you are right. That is the dependency graph. But I dont know how to build this? IS there any java package or tools available for that

Answer (score 3):

You must have solved the problem, but i think this may help others.
You may want to check the [Stanford parser homepage](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

You can find [tydevi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tydevi/) and [DependenSee](http://chaoticity.com/dependensee-a-dependency-parse-visualisation-tool/) where

- `tydevi` is typed Dependency Viewer that makes a picture of the Stanford Dependencies analysis of a sentence (By Bernard Bou), and
- `DependenSee` is a Dependency Parse Visualisation Tool that makes pictures of Stanford Dependency output.

Comment: It is `tydevi` not `typedvi`. The link is https://sourceforge.net/projects/tydevi/

Answer (score 0):

@Sakthi here is an implementation http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=topological-sort

You can also implement your own quick implementation using a Node class with left & right pointers.

XML DOM object also can be leveraged. Advantage with that is, you can use XPATH. Disadvantage is, it is a very costly implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you must have already found the answer but just in case. There is a method toDotFormat() that can be called on dependencies. This allows to store the result in DOT format which can be easily read as a graph using GraphViz. Using GV you can render it in many different formats such as png.