# How can i determine the head word in a Sentence, using NLP?

Tags: python, nlp

For example, if I have been given a  sentence:

> A British soldier was killed in the fighting in Afghanistan

The head word of that sentence is "killed".

How can I find it, given the nltk package in Python? I am not talking about stemming, I refer to the head word.

Comment: nope as i said it is not stemming

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "_the_ root word of the sentence"?

Comment: A stemming algorithm reduces the words "fishing", "fished", and "fisher" to the root word, "fish" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming.  Do you mean something different? At a glance, I'd say your sentence contains two root words: "kill" and "fight".

Comment: yeah exactly.. if you read the work of Katja fillipova, http://aclweb.org/anthology/D/D13/D13-1155.pdf she considers 'kill' a root word. How does she do that?

Comment: Is this a grammer or a programming question?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is unclear. OP has provided examples, as well as cited a relevant paper to give a very clear picture of what s/he wants.

Comment: user2878953 - You cite two different libraries. "NLP" in the title, and "NLTK" in the body. You might pick one and then add a sentence explaining what it is. That could help getting the question reopened (not everyone Googles for the terms).

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the **head word** Sentence Parsing.

It's available in Python's nltk package, as you can see in this [link](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html#fig-depgraph0).

It's also much related to Dependency Parsing, as you can see from Stanford NLP package in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280467/stanford-dependency-parser) and explained quite a bit in this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)#More_trees)